# Deleting an undeletable Directory in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, directory

I have encountered a problem from time to time but have not been able to resolve it without formatting.

I have a directory called `d:\DotNet` that I want to delete. I cannot because inside this folder there is another folder called: `T4 Code generation and Misc.`

When I try to deleting or access `T4 Code generation and Misc.`, I get the following error:

> Could not find this item
>
> This is no longer located in D:\DotNet. Verify this item's location and try again.

Hopefully this is a simple fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open `CMD` and `CD` into the location where the file is at
2. Type `dir /a /x /p` which will show you the hidden files and the 8.3 filenames which usually look like: `C:Progra~1`
3. Since it is a folder you want to delete, run `rd /s <8.3name>`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have seen this problem several times over the course of YEARS.

Comment: Your welcome, just glad it helped.  I had this and it took me forever to figure it out so I am happy to be able to share it.